Slicer is not locked, but after excel worksheet is protected, slicer still not work. ,
Slicer is not locked, but after excel worksheet is protected, slicer still not work. what can I do?

To keep the ability to use a slicer on a protected sheet, you must allow:

Use Autofilter
Edit objects

Refer to the screenshot:

If locked in VBA, refer to the arguments presented on the help page.
